# Given matrix A. To find $A^{2010}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $\theta = 2\pi/67$. Now consider the matrix
>   $$
>  A =
>  \begin{pmatrix}
>   \phantom{-}\cos \theta & \sin \theta \\
>   -\sin \theta & \cos \theta
>  \end{pmatrix}.
> $$
>   Then the matrix $A^{2010}$ is
>
> \begin{align*}
>  &\text{(A)}\;
>  \begin{pmatrix}
>   \phantom{-}\cos \theta & \sin \theta \\
>    -\sin \theta & \cos \theta
>  \end{pmatrix},
>  &
>  &\text{(B)}\;
>  \begin{pmatrix}
>   1 & 0 \\
>   0 & 1
>  \end{pmatrix}, \\
>  &\text{(C)}\;
>  \begin{pmatrix}
>   \phantom{-}\cos^{30} \theta & \sin^{30} \theta \\
>    -\sin^{30} \theta & \cos^{30} \theta
>  \end{pmatrix},
>  &
>  &\text{(D)}\;
>  \begin{pmatrix}
>   \phantom{-}0 & 1 \\
>   -1 & 0
>  \end{pmatrix}.
> \end{align*}

I think answer is B. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $A$ is a rotation matrix that takes a vector and rotates it by $1/67$th of a revolution. Now notice that $2010 = 67 \times 30$, so the answer is indeed (B).

Comment: The signs on the $\sin \theta$ terms are reversed from what is usually considered the standard rotation matrices, so it takes a small bit of rewriting to express that this is a clockwise (instead of the usual counter-clockwise) rotation.

Comment: @Aaron Quite right, didn't notice that. I've reworded.

Comment: @user can you explain line 2 of answer

Comment: @TaylorTed If you rotate $1/67$th of a circle $67 x 30$ times, where do you end up?

Comment: @user as far as i have understood it, your saying that this matrix rotates given point by angle $2\pi/67$.And we are to apply this transformation 2010 times so final rotated angle will be $2pi/67 * 2010=60\pi$

Comment: @TaylorTed Yes. And rotating by $60\pi$ does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
A=PDP^{-1}
$$
where
\begin{align*}
P &=
\begin{bmatrix}
i & -i \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&
D &=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta+i\sin\theta & 0 \\
0 & \cos\theta-i\sin\theta
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
[De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) then implies
\begin{align*}
A^{2010}
&= PD^{2010} P^{-1} \\
&= P
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(2010\,\theta)+i\sin(2010\,\theta) & 0 \\
0 & \cos(2010\,\theta)-i\sin(2010\,\theta)
\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}\\
&=
P
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(60\,\pi) & \sin(60\,\pi) \\
-\sin(60\,\pi) & \cos(60\,\pi)
\end{bmatrix}
P^{-1} \\
&=
P
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
P^{-1} \\
&= PIP^{-1} \\
&= PP^{-1} \\
&= I
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

$A$ can be thought as $e^{-i\theta}$. So that for the natural homeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2:x+iy \mapsto (x,y)$, $(\phi^{-1}\circ A\circ \phi )(z)=e^{-i\theta } z$. Hence, $(\phi^{-1} \circ A^{2010} \circ \phi)(z)= e^{- 2010 i \theta} z = e^{-60\pi i}z=z$. Hence, the answer is (B).